# Agile testing and traditional testing methods

Tags: testing, agile

How does agile testing differ from tradition, structured testing?

Comment: Testing in agile doesn't mean not structured!

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as "agile testing," but something that's often presented as a key component of the agile methodology is [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), which predates agile. How this differs from "traditional, structured testing" would depend on what you mean by that.

Other things often presented in the context of agile and unit testing that may be causing your confusion: [Test driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development) and [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Comment: I agree fully. I would say that there is no difference as 'agile' is an attitude of collaboration. Issue is if code is written and then thrown to QA for testing in a "them and us" attitude or if there is an attitude to write software that works and discover what is required.

Comment: That has little to do with agile and more to do with professional pride and good testing habits. Regardless of whether you are using TDD or CI, or whether your team is agile or not, you should be ensuring that your code works and is of good quality. TDD and CI certainly make that easier, of course!

Answer (score 1):

An agile project will normally place greater emphasis on *automated* testing, for integration and acceptance tests as well as unit tests,  because manual testing soon becomes too slow to allow frequent releases.

TDD methods change the emphasis from "testing to find defects" towards "testing as a design technique".

The mindet may be very different - an agile project uses tests to enable rapid refactoring and change - you can make major changes without fear because the tests will tell you what is working. Traditional projects fear change; their tests may not be structured in the same way and may inhibit change.

Comment: I don't entirely agree [with the comment that has just been deleted!]- I think the main benefit of TDD is that it pushes you to write more testable code. In general, more testable code is *better* code in other ways too. In other words, testability does not *conflict* with other non-functional requirements; it is in harmony with them. TDD *is* a way of designing the interface before writing code that uses that interface. Designing an interface on paper can only take you so far, without a disproportionate amount of effort.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, of course, on how you define "traditional structured testing" and "agile testing"...

This is what I've tended to observe with testing on the most effective agile teams I've seen.

- There isn't a separate testing group. Testers work within the development team - not separate from it.
- Testing is an ongoing process that happens throughout the development process - not something that happens in a separate phase after development.
- Testing is done by the whole team, rather than just by testers. The most obvious example of this is the tests that result from TDD - but it happens in other places too (e.g. product owners often get involved in helping define the higher level acceptance tests around stories being done).
- Testers act as educators and facilitators of testing by/for the whole team - rather than the bottleneck that controls all testing.
- The relationship between testers and non-testers tends to be more collaborative/collegiate rather than adversarial.
- Generally I find testers get more respect on agile teams.
- Testers get involved much earlier in the process, making it easier to ensure a system is produced that's easy to test.

Comment: Maybe as an addition: Because in an agile team you deliver more often than in classic development, testing abilities are more complex. They include especially automating tasks to get a quicker result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that the actual piece that includes testing the software can be fairly similar.

The largest difference is that way you get there.  Generally in an agile environment you work on small pieces of development that go to production relativity quickly.  This could be anywhere from a month to 2 week periods.

These smaller stories and faster deadlines require more light weight requirements and smaller pieces of development that are decided by the entire team. There is no period where a tester spends his time writing up a test strategy document.  Smaller iterations allows for testers to focus on only testing.

Encouraging everyone to be on the same page generally reduces the amount of rework.  With everyone working on smaller pieces, generally software is built and deployed more often.  This leads to a strong emphasis on a well built CI environment.  CI is 600 page topic as it is, so i'll leave it for you to research further.

For me the biggest difference is the mentality on the team.  Everyone is working together to release software.  Agile does a nice job of eliminating the developer vs tester standoff.  Instead of arguing over who is at fault (bad test, bad code, bad requirement, etc)  The group works together to fix it.  The company must encourage this for it to happen naturally, by eliminating defect counting or other stats that prevent team work.

Answer (score 0):

What ever the methodology you follow, basics of Product Quality is same. What has changed from  waterfall to agile is that testing is started very early in the sprint and how testing is performed. And the emphasis of testing has improved with practices such as TDD.

Starting from Unit testing to system test and acceptance testing, all these testing are in place with new way of doing it. Ex: Now while development is happening, Tester can involved in sessions like 'show me sessions'  which he can give early feedback.

Working in sprints has induce us to do regression testing in each cycle and acceptance testing before the demo. So how things do is changed from agile to waterfall (structured testing)